# I keep getting this error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep getting this error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[80];
    int length[10];
    length == sizeof(name)
    printf("What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("The length of your name is %s", length);
}
```

## EDIT

Okay so here's my new code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) 
{
    char name[20];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("There are %d letters in your name", strlen(name));
}
```

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: `length == sizeof(name)` not sure what this is doing stuck in the middle of your code.  You're using an equality operator and not an assignment operator, and you don't have an ending semi-colon.  Also, `sizeof` isn't going to tell you the length of a name a person hasn't even typed yet (see `strlen` and call it in the right place.)  And, as noted, you're using `%s` to print an `int`.

Comment: That's not much information to go on but be careful with format specifiers. In particular your last printf uses `%s` which expects a string but you pass it an int. That could be it. There's not much information in this question though.

Comment: @scott_fakename: He's actually passing an `int*`.

Comment: @EdS. Oh yep. That's true good catch. Looks like I did the same thing as him -- mistook what type of variable I was dealing with.

Comment: your edited code works perfectly fine. [link]http://ideone.com/vaCS82

Comment: How long is the name you are entering?  Define "doesn't work"

Answer (score 8):

```
printf("The length of your name is %s", length);
```

`%s` is for strings.  The format specifier for `int` is `%d`.  Passing in a type which does not match results in undefined behavior.

Aside from that, you have declared `length` as an array of int (wrong) and `length == sizeof(name)` 1. checks for equality, and 2. does nothing as you do not use the result.  It's a no-op.  Even if you used the assignment operator (`=`) it would still be wrong as arrays are not assignable and the return value of `sizeof` is not an array anyway.

The next problem is that `sizeof` will return the size of the array, in bytes, not the length of the string you read into it. In this case, `sizeof name` will always return `80`. To find the logical length of a string (the length up to the null terminator), use `strlen`.  So...

```
int main(void)
{
    char name[80];
    printf("What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("The length of your name is %zu\n", strlen(name));
}
```

Finally, use `fgets` instead of `scanf` to avoid buffer overruns.

```
fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
```

Comment: Furthermore, mismatched print/scan family format specifiers are now checked by compilers, which should have made this even more obvious. Make sure you are running the compiler with all warnings on.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to leave a comment and ask what compiler he was using.

Comment: Ok i did that and got the following error message 'cc     name.c   -o name
name.c: In function ‘main’:
name.c:10:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
  printf("Their are %d letters in your name", strlen(name););
                                                          ^
name.c:10:58: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat=]
make: *** [name] Error 1
'

Answer (score 0):

length == sizeof(name)

missing ';' before identifier 'printf'.And you should return a value in the main function.

printf("The length of your name is %s", length);

%s is for string,you should use %d for int.